# Arduino how to create wifi access point with ESP2668?

Tags: c++, arduino, wifi, esp8266, hotspot

I am using Arduino type device RobotDyn WiFi D1 R2 with builtin ESP8266 WiFi module. There are two photos:
[image]
I want to create WiFi access point using official library taken from there:

https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.0-beta2/installing.html

Please, look at my sketch (code):

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> // Include the Wi-Fi library
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>

const char *ssid = "ESP8266Test";  // The name of the Wi-Fi network that will be created
const char *password = "vadimn231"; // The password required to connect to it, leave blank for an open network

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

void handleRoot() {
  server.send(200, "text/html", "<h1>You are connected</h1>");
  // Go to http://192.168.4.1 in a web browser connected to this access point to see it.
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.softAP(ssid); // Start the access point

  Serial.println("");
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("Access Point IP address: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);
  Serial.print("Access Point \"");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  Serial.println("\" started");

  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();

  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

This code is working but not creating WiFi HotSpot. So, question is: How to create working access point on Arduino using ESP8266?
I will be grateful for any help or advice!

Thank you!

P. S. Sometimes, I can force it work. How: First connect Arduino to any existing network, and after it everything works. But I doubt, that it is correct solution.

P. P. S. You can download sketch directly there: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sWYOxqG3EaeYfM6akXVU5omP3jr7Ki2c

Comment: Have you looked here? https://www.engineersgarage.com/tutorials/esp8266-wifi-hotspot

Comment: Thank you for reply, in their example there is mostly my code. Anyway, I just tried it. it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your TCP IP settings don't get initialized, with this code, but they get set when you connect it to external wifi via the DHCP server.

I have this function which works for me. You might want to try it.

```
ConfigAndStartAp(){
  while(!(WiFi.softAPConfig(IPAddress(192, 168, 4, 2) , IPAddress(192, 168, 4, 2) , IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0) )));
  while(!(WiFi.softAP( ssid)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sorry, it's not working. Where I should put and call this function?

Comment: Place the function before setup, and call it in setup by replacing WiFi.softAP call

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very interesting approach.